# How to extract first 8 characters from a string in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, substring

I have column in a dataframe  and i am trying to extract 8 digits from a string. How can I do it

```
    Input
 Shipment ID
20180504-S-20000
20180514-S-20537
20180514-S-20541
20180514-S-20644
20180514-S-20644
20180516-S-20009
20180516-S-20009
20180516-S-20009
20180516-S-20009
```

**Expected Output**

```
Order_Date
20180504
20180514
20180514
20180514
20180514
20180516
20180516
20180516
20180516
```

I tried below code and it didnt work.

```
data['Order_Date'] = data['Shipment ID'][:8]
```

Comment: try delimiting option first, if that allows in your case

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You are close, need indexing with `str` which is apply for each value of `Serie`s:

```
data['Order_Date'] = data['Shipment ID'].str[:8]
```

For better performance if no `NaN`s values:

```
data['Order_Date'] = [x[:8] for x in data['Shipment ID']]
```

---

```
print (data)
        Shipment ID Order_Date
0  20180504-S-20000   20180504
1  20180514-S-20537   20180514
2  20180514-S-20541   20180514
3  20180514-S-20644   20180514
4  20180514-S-20644   20180514
5  20180516-S-20009   20180516
6  20180516-S-20009   20180516
7  20180516-S-20009   20180516
8  20180516-S-20009   20180516
```

If omit `str` code filter column by position, first N values like:

```
print (data['Shipment ID'][:2])
0    20180504-S-20000
1    20180514-S-20537
Name: Shipment ID, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `str.extract`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Shipment ID': ['20180504-S-20000', '20180514-S-20537', '20180514-S-20541', '20180514-S-20644', '20180514-S-20644', '20180516-S-20009', '20180516-S-20009', '20180516-S-20009', '20180516-S-20009']})
df["Order_Date"] = df["Shipment ID"].str.extract(r"(\d{8})")
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
       Shipment ID Order_Date
0  20180504-S-20000   20180504
1  20180514-S-20537   20180514
2  20180514-S-20541   20180514
3  20180514-S-20644   20180514
4  20180514-S-20644   20180514
5  20180516-S-20009   20180516
6  20180516-S-20009   20180516
7  20180516-S-20009   20180516
8  20180516-S-20009   20180516
```

Answer (score 2):

I decided to use `.str` accessor with subsetting:

```
data['p_dt'] = data['timestamp'].astype(str).str[:8]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also decide to delete from `-S` to the end

```
df["Order_Date"]=df['Shipment ID'].replace(regex=r"\-.*",value="")
df
        Shipment ID Order_Date
0  20180504-S-20000   20180504
1  20180514-S-20537   20180514
2  20180514-S-20541   20180514
3  20180514-S-20644   20180514
4  20180514-S-20644   20180514
5  20180516-S-20009   20180516
6  20180516-S-20009   20180516
7  20180516-S-20009   20180516
8  20180516-S-20009   20180516
```

Also you can capture the first 8 digits then delete everything and replace back with a backreference of the captured group:

```
df['Shipment ID'].replace(regex=r"(\d{8}).*",value="\\1")
```