# Is it possible to set the maximum string length with pandas (like SQL)

Tags: python, pandas

It is easy to set a column to a string data type with pandas either when you read it in a dataframe or once it's made. I should note that a categorical won't work because nearly every row has a different value.

Reading in:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data', dtype={'colA': string})
```

Afterwards:

```
df['colA'] = df['colA'].astype(str)
```

In SQL, you can set a limit on string length for a column, which will conserve memory. For example, I can set the max character length for a column by setting its data type to `varchar(100)`. I want to reduce the memory usage of a string column in a pandas dataframe. I can't read it in chunks because there are certain things that I need every value in it for, but I know there is a maximum string length (strings won't be more than 25 characters). Is there an equivalent to `varchar(100)` in pandas; something like `df.astype(string, maxlength=25)`?

The purpose of this is to reduce the memory needed to read this column.

Comment: [You cut everything after the first 25 strings in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51607400/how-to-extract-first-8-characters-from-a-string-in-pandas). [But this may give you better ways to reduce memory using pandas that are more effective](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/pandas-load-less-data/).

Answer (score 0):

try: df[‘column_name’].astype(|S25)